# coldfusion sql query to check user

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Trying to match received data from the form with one in the db. So if I dump form variable and the table I can see there is a match but coldfusion gives me this...

> Column 'Kirill' is either not in any table in
>   the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside
>   the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and
>   is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE
>   statement then 'Kirill' is not a column in the target table.

The query:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, PASSWORD 
from APP.USERS_TASK
where FIRST_NAME = "#form.username#"
  and PASSWORD = "#form.password#"
```

Also the same thing works just fine with id which been passed via url. With the different table though.

Comment: Perhaps you need single quotes instead of double quotes, e.g. `... FIRST_NAME = '#form.username#' ...`? (SQL injection possible?)

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but [passwords should be hashed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database/1054033#1054033).

Comment: It's actually illegal to store passwords in plaintext depending on what you're doing. Leigh is right.

Comment: lol, i'm just learning so no commercial projects so far. thx a lot btw. i'll do that.

Answer (score 6):

SQL requires strings to be in single quotes, not double.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, PASSWORD 
FROM APP.USERS_TASK
WHERE FIRST_NAME = '#form.username#'
AND PASSWORD = '#form.password#'
```

But really, you should be using [cfqueryparam](https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) to sanitize your user inputs and prevent SQL injection. This would also take care of any data typing and required quotes for you.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, PASSWORD 
FROM APP.USERS_TASK
WHERE FIRST_NAME = <cfqueryparam value="#form.username#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
AND PASSWORD = <cfqueryparam value="#form.password#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
```

Comment: Oh, didnt know quotes matters.
When using cfparam is it necessary to provide type info?

Comment: the `cfsqltype` attribute is not required, but it is recommended as it protects your database and makes sure that values are converted to string or numbers properly for you.

Comment: It's also great for converting dates/times as necessary. Those are always a pain to get right.

Comment: *cfsqltype .. is not required, but it is recommended* Ditto.  Always use the appropriate cfsqltype for the db column. Otherwise, the db has to guess ... and often guesses wrong, leading to inefficient queries - or worse - wrong query results.